# ReplayKit access to recording and custom preview actions

Tags: ios, swift, screen-recording, replaykit

I am using the replayKit to record my game. After the recording is done, I want to upload the video to my server. 
1. How do I access the recording from my app
2. The preview has "save" and "cancel" actions. How do I make my own custom actions like "share" etc?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @Ros did you find any solution for this ?